# printing Kwargs in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, keyword-argument

I have been trying to execute this code for printing out the keyword argument in for loop. I tried using both the f-string literals and .format() method, but it is giving output in 2 lines taking one value at a time. Can someone please point out what is going wrong in this code?

```py
def myfunc(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    for item in kwargs:
        print(f"my fruit of choice is : {kwargs['fruit']} and my veggie is: {kwargs['veggie']}")

myfunc(fruit='Apple',veggie='Lettuce')
```

Comment: What is the actual and expected output?

Comment: my expected answer was:' my fruit of choice is : Apple and my veggie is: Lettuce' which is to print in one string but the actual output is displaying 2 strings as "{'fruit': 'Apple', 'veggie': 'lettuce'}
my fruit of choice is : Apple and my veggie is: lettuce
my fruit of choice is : Apple and my veggie is: lettuce" . Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You loop over items in kwargs, of where there are two. Hence, you get two lines. There's no need for the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for the loop with two items, as mentioned in the comments, but here is a corrected version with a loop that will work for an arbitrary number of inputs:

```
def myfunc(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    stringlist = []
    for i, item in enumerate(kwargs):
        if i == 0:
            string = f"my {item} of choice is: {kwargs[item]}"
        else:
            string = f"my {item} is: {kwargs[item]}"
        stringlist.append(string)
    stringlist[-1] = "and " + stringlist[-1]
    if len(kwargs) >= 3:
        print(', '.join(stringlist)+'.')
    else: 
        print(' '.join(stringlist)+'.')

myfunc(fruit='Apple',veggie='Lettuce')
```

I wouldn't use the colons, since they aren't grammatically correct, but I left them in to match your original expected output.